# How to Make Laravel Eloquent "IN" Query?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I want to make query in Laravel Eloquent like here its raw MySQL query

```
SELECT  * from  exampleTbl where id in(1,2,3,4)
```

I have tried this in Laravel Eloquent but it's not working

```
DB::where("id IN(23,25)")->get()
```

Answer (score 349, accepted):

Here is how you do in Eloquent

```
$users = User::whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```

And if you are using Query builder then :

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```

Answer (score 20):

If you are using Query builder then you may use a blow

```
DB::table(Newsletter Subscription)
->select('*')
->whereIn('id', $send_users_list)
->get()
```

If you are working with Eloquent then you can use as below

```
$sendUsersList = Newsletter Subscription:: select ('*')
                ->whereIn('id', $send_users_list)
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 11):

**Syntax:**

```
$data = Model::whereIn('field_name', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

Use for **Users** Model

```
$usersList = Users::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

Answer (score 10):

As @Raheel Answered it will be fine but if you are working with `Laravel 6/7`

Then use Eloquent `whereIn` Query.

**Example1:**

```
$users = User::wherein('id',[1,2,3])->get();
```

**Example2:**

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

**Example3:**

```
$ids = [1,2,3];

$users = User::wherein('id',$ids)->get();
```

Comment: This is literally the same code as the accepted answer posted 5 years prior. What is the point of this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you wanna use `whereRaw($query)`

Your Code :

```
DB::where("id IN(23,25)")->get()
```

Into :

```
DB::whereRaw("id IN(23,25)")->get()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Laravel 5.7, there is a method **whereIntegerInRaw**. The execution time is faster than **whereIn**.

```
User::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();

User::whereIntegerInRaw('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

You can see the [PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26434).

Comment: Useful for performance. Thanks for your information.