# Grouping multiple where clauses with OR in Laravel on one single orWhere function

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I want to select from the database something like: `SELECT * FROM database WHERE id=1 OR id=2 OR id=5;`

I do not know the number of the where clauses that the user will request, it can be one, it can be 10.

I tried using `Model::orWhere([['id','=',1],['id','=',2],['id','=',5]])` but it seems to be returning an empty list.

In the `Laravel` documentation, there is this example for the `WHERE` clause:

```
users = DB::table('users')->where([
    ['status', '=', '1'],
    ['subscribed', '<>', '1'],
])->get();
```

While the `WHERE` clause it working as in the example,  `orWhere` clause doesn't seem to work like this though.

Comment: You could use and IN Clause https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115385/how-to-make-laravel-eloquent-in-query

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM database WHERE id=1 OR id=2 OR id=5;` works for you ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz yes, I tested the clauses on something that should return.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, then please close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from my comment you can us an IN Clause could solve this.

```
$model = Model::whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
```

Reference [How to Make Laravel IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115385/how-to-make-laravel-eloquent-in-query)

Answer (score 2):

Use something like:

```
User::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

As second parameter you need to use an array.