# How to combine four select queries which select an equal number of rows randomly into one?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

The following is my db table:

```
 id category_id name
--------------------
  1     4        A
  2     5        B
  3     6        C
```

I have four simple select queries which pull 15 rows by random from specific categories:

```
select * from table where category_id = 4 order by rand() limit 15;
select * from table where category_id = 5 order by rand() limit 15;
select * from table where category_id = 6 order by rand() limit 15;
select * from table where category_id = 7 order by rand() limit 15;
```

I want to combine them into a single query rather than four separate queries. I've tried using the `UNION` operator but it wasn't pulling 15 rows EQUALLY from each category:

```
(
    select * from table where category_id = 4 
    union 
    select * from table where category_id = 5
    union 
    select * from table where category_id = 6
    union 
    select * from table where category_id = 7 
) order by rand() limit 60;
```

How can I achieve this? Or, do I have to run separate queries?

<sup>I've tagged Laravel because I'm using Laravel as the backend and maybe Eloquent has a smarter way to achieve this.</sup>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917558/laravel-eloquent-or-fluent-random-row and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115385/how-to-make-laravel-eloquent-in-query

Comment: It should be something DB::table('table')->whereIn('category_id', [4,5,6,7])->inRandomOrder()->limit(15)->get();

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? You may be able to do this with window functions.

Comment: @flakerimi Those don't solve my original question. That gets 15 rows from specific categories in random order. I need 15 random rows from EACH of those categories (total 60 rows).

Comment: @BillKarwin I am indeed using v8. I'll look into window functions as I've not come accross them before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this one?:

```
    (select * from table where category_id = 4 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 15)
    union all
    (select * from table where category_id = 5 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 15)
    union all 
    (select * from table where category_id = 6 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 15)
    union all
    (select * from table where category_id = 7 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 15)
```

Comment: Ah, I just figured it out and switched tabs to find your answer. The only difference is I'm intentionally not using `union all`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()` as such

````
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT id, 
           category_id, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category_id 
                                 ORDER BY RAND() DESC) AS rank
      FROM table)
 SELECT *
   FROM CTE
 WHERE rank <= 15 AND category_id IN (4,5,6,7)```
````

Comment: I'm not seeing the randomness in this?

Comment: You should use `OVER(PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY RAND())`