# Eloquent raw query in parameter

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have laravel eloquent example query:

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.id IN :param', ['param' => [1, 2, 3]]);
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I bind this array parameter to query.

In symfony I could use ->setParameter('param', Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY);
But I dont see option do it the same in Laravel.

Regards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115385/how-to-make-laravel-eloquent-in-query   maybe this will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

otherway, You can use a string and a Mark selector insteade of param :

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.id IN (?)', ['1, 2, 3']);
```

Answer (score 0):

use eloquent **whereIn** to find the users in the params array.

```
$params = [1,2,3]
User::whereIn("id", $params)->get();
```

Comment: for DB query you can use 
$params = [1,2,3]
$users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $params)->get();

Answer (score -1):

If you are using eloquent than you can do this ...

```
$id = [1,2,3];
$data = Model::find($id);
```

reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

if you are using db query than you can do like this way ...

```
$data = DB::table('users')
                ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                ->get();
```

reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

may it helps you ...

Comment: As I wrote it was only example query. My real query is much more complicate and I can't use anything related to model.